# IOS - React-Native When pressing the back button fon the header it's activating onBlur of components

Tags: react-native

I need a little help how to avoid the situation i'm in...

I have a component that is using onBlur={}, but when i'm pressing the back button on the header the onBlur is being activating... couldn't find a way around.

Any one know how to avoid it?

tried to find any other way without using the onBlur, but i need it.

Comment: What is the problem when the ```onBlur```get called? Show us where and why do you need ```onBlur ```?

Comment: I have a screen with some components and functions, one of the components using onBlur method, and when i'm blurring the component it works as it need to, but the same onBlur is getting triggered also when i'm going back to a previous page (pressing back on the header), and i don't want the back button to trigger onBlur from a component inside the page...

Comment: Please provide Screen shot of it